# Unknown slow sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, amazon-cloudwatch

While I'm exploring logs from [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), I found some queries I can't explain

```
# Time: 190726 1:05:16
# User@Host: company[company] @ [210.10.5.183] Id: 938
# Query_time: 238.040510 Lock_time: 0.000033 Rows_sent: 8988370 Rows_examined: 8988370
use application;
SET timestamp=1564103116;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `dictionary_translations`;

# Time: 190726 1:09:53
# User@Host: company[company] @ [210.10.5.183] Id: 938
# Query_time: 277.528088 Lock_time: 0.000035 Rows_sent: 3223714 Rows_examined: 3223714
SET timestamp=1564103393;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `email_events`;

...
```

As you can see these queries took a lot time, it must be optimized.

The application runs on rails, maybe Active Record is doing some synchronization?

What is the 'nature' of these queries? How it can be optimized?

Comment: There is no `WHERE` clause. You are getting every record in the the dictionary. That's 8 million rows. Depending on how you use it, you may want to limit it.

Comment: dictionary_translations  is a view  ..  or is a flat table??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of this  queries may be result of running mysqldump while backing up database